# difference between ~/bin vs /usr/local/bin on mac

Tags: macos, command-line

I have a few exec scripts that I want to run on my command line.

Which folder should I place them in `~/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`?

What is the difference between both of these folders?

Which is the be used when?

Comment: Short answer just so you know what to do for now: ~/usr/local/bin. I'll let someone else explain why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use ~/bin (or some similar location inside your home directory) if you want the scripts to be available *only* to your user account (not other user accounts, including root). Essentially, this'd be your personal bin folder where you can do whatever you want without disturbing other users. You'll also have to add this to your PATH (in ~/.bash_profile, ~/.profile, or whatever).

If you want the scripts to be available under all user accounts OR don't have any other user accounts OR just don't care, use /usr/local/bin instead. This'll save the hassle of editing your PATH, and is generally a more standard location.

Comment: `~/.bash_profile` is definitely the best place in OSX to add PATH and other environment vars, aliases, etc.

Comment: @l'L'l: It depends -- if you sometimes use other sh-family shells (zsh, ksh, sh, etc), a setting in ~/.profile will apply to those as well. Also, if you already have a ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile, it's important to put it in the one that exists (or both, if they both exist).